# Grafana charts grouped by month with Google BigQuery Datasource?

Tags: google-bigquery, grafana

I use Grafana (the version is 8.3.3) with the Google BigQuery datasource.

I can't display a graph with a monthly distribution (with the macro $__timeGroup)

My query :

```
SELECT * FROM (   SELECT
    $__timeGroup(usage_start_time, 1M),
    project.id AS metric,
    SUM(cost) AS value   FROM
    `project.view_v3`   WHERE
    $__timeFilter(usage_start_time)   GROUP BY 1, 2   ORDER BY 1 ASC ) WHERE value > 0
```

With a visualization by table, it seems to work, but not in graphical mode :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlxqP.jpg)

thanks for helping,
Regards,
Didier